# Synax Highlighting w/ Dynamic Scriptblock

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm creating a dynamic ScriptBlock the way below so I can use local functions and variables and easily pass them to remote computers via Invoke-Command. The issue is that since all the text inside Create is enclosed with double quotes, I loose all my syntax highlighting since all editors see the code as one big string.

While this is only a cosmetic issue, I'd like to find a work around that allow my code to be passed without having double quotes. I've tried passing a variable inside Create instead of the actually text, but it does not get interpreted.

```
function local_admin($a, $b) {
([adsi]"WinNT://localhost/Administrators,group").Add("WinNT://$a/$b,user")
}

$SB = [ScriptBlock]::Create(@"

    #Define Function
    function local_admin {$Function:local_admin}

    local_admin domain username
"@)


Invoke-Command -ComputerName server2 -ScriptBlock $SB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function into the remote session using the following example. This allows you to define the `ScriptBlock` using curly braces instead of as a string.

```
# Define the function
function foo {
    "bar";
}

$sb = {
    # Import the function definition into the remote session
    [void](New-Item -Path $args[0].PSPath -Value $args[0].Definition);
    # Call the function
    foo;
    };

#(gi function:foo) | select *
Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList (Get-Item -Path function:foo);
```

Here is a modified version of your function. Please take note that the domain and username can be dynamically passed into the remote `ScriptBlock` using the `-ArgumentList` parameter. I am using the `$args` automatic variable to pass objects into the `ScriptBlock`.

```
function local_admin($a, $b) {
    ([adsi]"WinNT://localhost/Administrators,group").Add("WinNT://$a/$b,user")
}

$SB = {
    #Define Function
    [void](New-Item -Path $args[0].PSPath -Value $args[0].Definition);
    # Call the function
    local_admin $args[1] $args[2];
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName server2 -ScriptBlock $SB -ArgumentList (Get-Item -Path function:local_admin), 'domain', 'username';
```

Comment: If I do that, the output is just: 

     $Function:local_admin 'code'

The function is never actually run.

Comment: I updated my answer - sorry, I misinterpreted your inquiry initially.

Comment: That works thanks! I did sort of like the [ScriptBlock]::Create approach since it could read all the local variables without having to declare them in the ArgumentList. 

Any thoughts on which is the better approach?

Comment: Neither approach is "better" per se, but I like the `-ArgumentList` approach. It just makes more sense in my mind, to pass objects into the remote session.

Comment: If you don't like -ArgumentList and are using V3 or greater, see 'help about_Remote_Variables', specifically look for the $using syntax.